# create and insert into temporary table using mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as follows.

Here I have created a temporary table named **tempDesTable** and put the data from database. Now I have to put additional data from another select query. But it shows `Error Code : 1327 Undeclared variable: tempDesTable`

```
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempDesTable AS (SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM t_users WHERE `DesignationID` = p_DesignationID AND BranchID = 0);      

    SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName INTO `tempDesTable` FROM t_users WHERE `DesignationID` = p_DesignationID AND BranchID = p_BranchID;

END$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use insert ... select rather than select ... into

```
INSERT INTO tempDesTable SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM t_users 
WHERE `DesignationID` = p_DesignationID AND BranchID = p_BranchID;
```